# How To Understand Tensor Flow Weights and Gradient Histogram

Tags: histogram, tensorflow

I am experimenting with conv nets for sentiment analysis.
I used a basic convent architecture.

[image: Network]

I am trying to analyze the learning, I have a bad feeling about weights, Although I am early in the learning process, but the weights for fully connected layer  essentially suggest no updates/ update on only very few component , because histogram essentially remains the same.

[image: Weight and Gradient Histogram]

Any hints on what I could be missing?

Regards,
Vaibhav Singh